# NTOP web interface?

Tags: network-monitoring, ntop

[NTOP](http://www.ntop.org) is a network monitor.
It has a web interface for viewing statistics.

I installed it via `sudo apt-get install ntop` on Ubuntu 2012.04, the daemon got started at the end of the install, without me doing anything special.

**QUESTION:** How to access the web interface?

`http://localhost:4242` says `Unable to connect`.

I tried stopping the daemon and launching it in various ways:

```
sudo ntop -P /etc/ntop -W4242 -d
sudo ntop -P /var/lib/ntop/ -W4242 -d
```

But still `Unable to connect`.

Comment: It should be `http://hostname:3000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

Comment: That's it! I had read 4242 on some web page so I wasn't looking further... Could you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Also allow port 3001 for password authentication.

Comment: and if you have a firewall, remember to allow tcp port 3000
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT add above your drop rule
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT that should do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can view and configure it through `http://hostname:3000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

ntop focuses on :

- Traffic measurement
- Traffic monitoring
- Network optimization and planning
- Detection of network security violations

You can also  go through the [documentation](http://www.ntop.org/support/documentation/) and [Man Pages](http://www.ntop.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/ntop-man.html) for optimum usage.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to access the web-gui for NTOP.

-w   --> This uses an unencrypted connection (the default).  Port 3000 unless overridden.
-W   --> Uses SSL encryption.

Examples:

1. Default Setup

   `sudo ntop -d`

   This would default to an unencrypted ntop service running on port 3000.  To connect you would type `http://[IP_ADDRESS_OF_SYSTEM]:3000` into the address bar of a web browser.
2. Encrypted Setup

   `sudo ntop -W 8080 -d`

This results in an encrypted ntop service running on port 8080.  To connect you would need to type `https://[IP_ADDRESS_OF_SYSTEM]:8080` into the address bar of a web browser.

Comment: When I set up ntop it asked for my network interfaces and administrator password - shouldn't it just launch itself?